# Configuring Cassandra with private IP for internode communications

Tags: ip, cassandra, private

I am trying to create a Cassandra cluster. For inter-node communications, on each node, I am using a separate interface with an internal IP address that is not accessible form outside. In addition each machine has an interface that has an external IP visible from outside.

Cluster works fine when a client can use internal addresses. But when I am trying to connect to a node using an external address, the connection itself works, but cluster is described to a client using internal addresses. As a result, client fails because it cannot connect to Cassandra nodes using reported internal addresses.

Is there a way to make Cassandra cluster to report DNS names (or external IPs) of the nodes instead their internal IP addresses?

Answer (score 2):

In `cassandra.yaml` set `listen_address` to the internal IP, and `rpc_address` to the external IP, just follow the instructions in the comments.

Comment: I have tried this. It does not help.  I am using Astyanax client library to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Just got this working, the change was with broadcast_rpc_address, change that to your external IP in the cassandra.yaml file and restart cassandra.